# Jetdrive 850 install on Macbook Pro 2015

Tags: high-sierra, startup, ssd

I have a Macbook Pro 2015 that I bought used. When I bought it, OS 10.13 (High Sierra) was installed, but the SSD was failing. I bought a JetDrive 850 to replace it, and put the High Sierra installer on an external USB hard drive.

When use the option key and choose "Install macOS High Sierra" from the USB drive, it takes me to the question mark folder.

Edited to add: When I try to boot to internet recovery, I get an 2002F error, which apparently indicates an internet connectivity. However, my WiFi is working fine for other devices.

What should I try?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by reformatting and recreating the Mac OS X High Sierra install disk using [DiskMaker X](http://diskmakerx.com/).

After that, I encountered another problem: the Transcend SSD had an MBR partition table, for which I needed [these instructions on changing the partition scheme to GUID](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300297/how-to-choose-guid-with-high-sierras-disk-utility).

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following procedure as detailed in the [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204323):

> **If your Mac doesn't start up**
>
> If your Mac starts up to a flashing question mark, but then doesn't
>   continue starting up, try these steps.
>
> 1) Turn off your Mac by pressing and holding the power button for a few seconds.
>
> 2) Press the power button once to turn your Mac back on. Immediately press and hold the Command and R keys on your keyboard to start your
>   Mac from macOS Recovery. Keep these two keys held down until you see
>   an Apple logo or globe.
>
> 3) If prompted, select a Wi-Fi network to connect to the Internet as part of startup.
>
> 4) After the macOS Utilities window appears, choose Startup Disk from the Apple menu.
>
> 5) Select your startup disk, then click Restart.
>
> If you don't see your startup disk in the Startup Disk window, close
>   the window and try the next sections of this article.
>
> [....]

Comment: Thanks. When I try to use internet recovery, I get a 2002F error.

Comment: Try to turn off wifi and install using an ethernet cable.

Comment: Thank you, but this Macbook has no wired Ethernet port.

Comment: If really needed you can still use a thunderbolt/ethernet adapter.