# Missing "view" button in disk utility

Tags: macos, disk-utility, encryption

I'm unable to encrypt an external hard drive because the encryption option seems to be missing. Various answers pointed to doing something with the 'partition' button, but that button is greyed out. To solve the greyed-out issue, evidently I first need to click on the 'view' button as [explained here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/301492/128636). But I have no view button! I want my view button, give me my view button!

(Specifically, I don't see a view button on my screen whereas it clearly shows up in [this explanation](https://blog.macsales.com/45330-disk-utility-view-options-solving-the-mystery-of-those-empty-unformatted-drives).)

Answer (score 1):

Speculation: The view button is missing because disk utility defaults changed and now everything is viewable by default.

As for the greyed out partition button, notice that the external drive tab has two levels, a parent and a child. The 'partition' button becomes un-greyed-out again if you click on the parent instead of the child. This seems to be working fine now.

Comment: I have no View button or menu option for it. Please help!